# Две бд как починить

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Есть две базы данных, вторая по сути бэкап с первой, но первая сильно повреждена по версии DBCC CHECK, но вторая работает исправно, как и чем можно их сравнить и починить поврежденную, имея доступ к работающей ?

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален?

Comment: он наверно всегда актуален будет)